# Pairing a chess match

Tags: probability

[image]

$$P(\text{player A is chosen}) = \frac{ \binom{1}{1}\binom{7}{3} }{\binom{8}{4}}$$

$$ P(\text{player B is chosen}) = \frac{ \binom{1}{1}\binom{8}{3} }{\binom{9}{4}} $$

$$P(\text{player A and B are paired}) = \frac{ \binom{4}{1} \binom{4}{1} }{\binom{8}{2}}$$

The way I see it we are looking for conditional probability:

$$P(\text{A and B are paired} | \text{A and B are chosen})  = \frac{P(\text{A and B are paired})}{P(\text{A chosen}) \cdot P(\text{B chosen}) }$$

then for b)

$$P(\text{A and B not paired but chosen}) =  \frac{1-P(\text{A and B paired)}}{P(\text{A chosen}) \cdot P(\text{B chosen})}$$

Is a) and b) correct?

The solution is:
[image]

But I do not understand it. Can somebody explain it?

Comment: No they are not, first truly you can solve this without conditional probability, and second the probability of $A$ and $B$ being paired is wrong. From 8 people there are $\binom{8}{2}$ possible pairs, from wich only one result in $A$ nad $B$ paired.

Comment: @TomKeen Can you maybe explain the solution (I edited the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample space is the set of all possible pairs between both clubs. There are $\binom{8}{4}$ waysof choosing the first team, for wich there are $\binom{9}{4}$ ways of chosing the second team, for wich there are $4!$ ways to pair once both teams have been chosen, so sample space has a cardinal of $\binom{8}{4}\binom{9}{4}*4!$. The pairing is done by fixing a group and making to permute all mebers from the other group.

a)There are $\binom{7}{3}$ possible teams having Rebecca as a member, for wich there are $\binom{8}{3}$ possible teams having Elise as a memeber, for wich there are $3!$ possible pairs given that Rebecca and Elisa are paired. Therefore there are $3!\binom{7}{3}\binom{8}{3}$ ways in wich Rebecca and Elise can be paired.

b)Considering incise a), from $4!$ possible pairs, there are $4!-3!=18$  pairs where Rebecca and Elise are not paired after choosing the teams, so the new event of interest has a cardinal of $18\binom{7}{3}\binom{8}{3}$.

Comment: I see, the pairs confused me since I didnt know where the permutations came from

Answer (score 1):

You are making this harder than it is. In a), the first stage, i.e. how many
are selected to the teams, is a red herring. All possible matches ($8\ast
9=72$) are equally likely. Hence the answer to $a$ is simply $1/72$.

In b) there is a $4/8=1/2$ chance that Rebecca will be chosen and a $4/9$
chance that Elise will be shosen. These events are independent so the
probability both will be chosen is $\frac{1}{2}\frac{4}{9}=\frac{2}{9}$.
Then simply subtract the probability in a) to get the answer, i.e. the
answer is $\frac{2}{9}-\frac{1}{72}=\frac{15}{72}$.

c) is simply $1$ minus the chance none of them will be chosen.